# Selenium Python refreshing a page with proxies until is fully loaded

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I want to monitor a page to get changes.
So I use proxies. Not all this proxies work (some maybe are banned some are to slow etc.) so I want to refresh page, and I want to change the proxy every refresh and if the page do not load until 2 seconds make a refresh.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % PROXY['http']) 

        while True:   
                try:
                    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options) 
                    browser.implicitly_wait(1) 
                    browser.get(links)
                    break
                except:
                    browser.close()
                    PROXY = proxy_reader.proxies_call(3)  #this function return a new proxy each time 

    source = browser.page_source
```

I don't know how to make every session during 2 seconds...
I hope someone can help me.

Comment: So you want to navigate to page and if it not loaded within 2 seconds - refresh the page and change the proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create sessions with new Proxy each time until page loaded within 2 seconds, try below solution

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

while True:
    PROXY = proxy_reader.proxies_call(3)
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument('--proxy-server=http://%s' % PROXY['http']) 
    browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=path, options=options)
    # Set page load timeout: if page not loaded within 2 seconds - raise TimeoutException
    browser.set_page_load_timeout(2)
    try:
        browser.get(links)
        break
    except TimeoutException:
        browser.quit()
```